# Reset a ComboBox

Tags: combobox, sapui5

I have a view that contains several ComboBox elements. For some reason old data remains from the previous time the view was opened and I would like to reset the combobox elements in the view every time it is opened. Is there a function that could that for me? I want it to be *exactly how it is as if I rendered it the first time with the initial items*. Would using `setSelectedItem(vItem)`, `setSelectedItemId(vItem)`, `setSelectedKey(sKey)`, `setShowSecondaryValues()` help? If so, what do these keywords mean (selectedItem, selectedItemID, selectedKey, secondaryValues)?

Comment: This [thread](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3775395) might be helpful.

Comment: Did you read the manual?

Comment: Thanks @Bouramas, do you know if doing so will reset the combo box to blank? I tried that and my boss told me there might be some leftover data so I want to be sure it's as if it's brand new. Do you know what `getDefaultSelectedItem()` would do?

Comment: Yes I did @matbtt, please tell SAP to fix their "Explored" page. It doesn't match up with the API reference and can be confusing for a newbie like me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you do not provide an example. Normally you bind your UI controls against a model, e.g. JSONModel. In this case the items of your ComboBox controls would be taken from the corresponding model. However, you can use method [removeAllItems](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ComboBoxBase.html#removeAllItems) to achieve the desired behaviour.

UPDATE: Obviously the controls are bound and only the selection should be cleared.
Use [setSelectedItem](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ComboBox.html#setSelectedItem) with value `null` to clear the selection. You could also use the binding to set the selected item automatically by using the selectedKey attribute, see [example](https://jsbin.com/cajenec/2/edit?html,output).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that my UI is binded against a model. Wouldn't `removeAllItems()` then erase all the options? I don't want to do that, I want the Combobox with all the items, just without any selections.

Comment: I updated the answer. Please try to describe your problem as exactly as possible. You have a model... then tell it. You want to clear the selection... then don't write that you want to reset the combox box to blank...